# How to request number for backpressure on Flowable.subscribe(onNext...)

Tags: rx-java

In RxJava 2.0, I want that Flowable signals an item one by one after onNext finsh its job.

```
f = Flowable.create(...).onBackpressureDrop();
f.subscribe(new Subscriber(){
    Subscription s;
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        this.s = s;
        s.request(1);
      }

    public void onNext(T t) {
        doHeavyTask(t);
        s.request(1);
    }
    ...
});
```

However, when I use subscribe method which returns Disposable, I cannot request the number for backpressure because onNext method cannot get Subscription.

```
Disposable d = f.subscribe(t -> {
   doHeavytask(t);
   ??? how can I call Subscription's request method?
});
```

Also, I found the subscribe method which has onSubscribe event as a parameter. However, Subscription would be called only once at onSubscribe, so it would stop after Flowable signal as many data as first request's number.

Therefore the number which only I can request might be Long.MAX_VALUE.

I want to know how to use subscribe method which returns Disposable with the control of Subscription's request.

Comment: Why do you need that information at the subscription call?

Comment: I want to drop items that a flowable created while a subscriber were working. I think that  my sample were too slappy, so I fix it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, end-consumers calling `request(1)` at start and after each element is just overhead (you usually don't have an async boundary in your `onNext` or `Consumer` that needs backpressure) so the initial default `Long.MAX_VALUE` should work for you. Each upstream operator that has an internal buffer will work out its bounded requesting pattern and you don't have to do much about it (maybe increase or reduce that buffer size on the operator to improve througput or save memory).

If you really want to have access to request and Disposable, use `ResourceSubscriber`: it has `onStart` and `request()` you can call to get started and keep going. Then use `subscribeWith` that will `subscribe()` and then return you the same Subscriber you passed in.

Comment: Thank you for the information! So, if I want to control the number of emitted items, I should handle an internal buffer instead of request method. Then, Once I set the buffer size, I don't have to warry about requesting the number, I guess. I may try it later!